# Menus open in wrong monitor

Tags: gnome, multi-monitor, gtk

I connected an external monitor to the HDMI port of my laptop and it worked; however, if I move any window there and try to open a menu on it, it will open on the wrong screen.

This is how it looks, the gnome-terminal window is open on the external monitor but, when I select the 'Terminal' menu, it opens on the main display. [image]

I am running Fedora 23 and have tried with GNOME 3, MATE and Cinnamon, they all show the same problem, but it only happens with GTK programs.

This is how the monitors are set (1 is the laptop, 2 is the external monitor - can't move it, it's mounted to the wall):

[image]

What to do?

Comment: I have this same problem running F23 / KDM / KDE

Comment: I remember this issue for years and my work-around is to put left-top-most monitor as primary. And use it mostly